# How to recover from 'An error occurred' in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

It happens every single bloody day.

At the beginning iTunes works fine. I can see my 'Recommendation' and 'Connect' in the 'For you' tab. However from time to time the following error message appears. It can happen multiple times in a day.

[image]

How can I recover from it short of restarting itune?  The 'OK' did nothing.

Comment: Does it occur if you click on "For You" or out of the blue? Did you try to log out from your iTunes account (within iTunes) and log in again?

Comment: I still haven't found a pattern yet. Usually just a matter of switching between 'Library', 'For you' and 'Browse' will trigger it. Too frustrating. And I am paying for the Music service... :-(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem the other day.

I signed out from my account (go to Account -> Sign out...) and then I quit iTunes. I signed in after relaunching and everything seems to be working. It has been working fine for the last two days.